# How to find out if my IIS is x64 or x86?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

As the title reads, I'm about to download and install URL Rewrite Go Live extension on my Windows Server 2008 R2 dedicated server, and I need to find out which version of URL Rewrite I should be downloading, x64 or x86.

The information that came with the server when I started to rent it said it was 64-bit but when I look at my C: directory I have two Program Files directories, one titled "Program Files" and the other "Program Files (86)" - so this has confused me somewhat.

Can anybody suggest how to find this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The architecture of your IIS binaries relies on the architecture of your OS. Having both `Programs Files` and `Program Files (x86)` folders is a sign of x64 Windows, so your IIS binaries are also x64.

Install the x64 version of URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is:

If you have an x64 OS, IIS is running as x64 *unless you changed it to x86*.

Now it is tricky to change it. You would know if you did it. There are a few reasons to do it, but fewer now than a few years ago.

So if you didn't change it, it is the same as the OS.